# How to reduce CRUD boilerplate in NGXS?

Tags: ngxs

Imagine I have two substates in my store one for each: **1.users** **2. Articles**

Both of these support CRUD (create, read, update delete).

To accomplish this I have to make atleast 7 actions for both of them.

Action list for Articles as an example:

```
1. GetAllArticle
2. GetArticleById
3. DeleteArticle
4. UpdateArticle
5. CreateArticle
6. LoadingStart
7. LoadingFinish
8. LoadingError
```

All 8 actions will be created for users as well along with their reducers/action handlers. This results in huge amounts of boilerplate for something very common and trivial.

**My question is if there is a way that I reduce the boilerplate and code repetition?**

Answer (score 3):

I guess it's a bit late answer, but still :D

First, I can immediately get rid of the three actions - `LoadingStart`, `LoadingFinish`, `LoadingError`. I'm not sure that you definitely get a profit from them, just because NGXS will return an error to the `onError` callback for you.

But also it depends on what you're calling "loading", is that applied to all requests or only to "articles"? If only to "articles" - it's much easier to create a state property called `loading`, something like:

```js
@State({
  name: 'articles',
  defaults: {
    loading: false,
    articles: []
  }
})
export class ArticlesState {}
```

Since NGXS can perform asynchronous work, in cases where you return a `Promise` or `Observable` - it's much better to apply the `finalize` operator, that will call a function when observable completes or errors, so you might not need `LoadingFinish` and `LoadingError`.

The second problem is your remaining 5 actions. This also depends on what you call "boilerplate", basically you cannot use 1 action for 5 actions :D Unless it's some generic action, that looks something like that:

```js
// Let's assume that it's some shared
// `enum` that's used in multiple places
// by multiple states
export const enum CrudOperation {
  GetAll,
  GetById,
  Delete,
  Update,
  Create
}

export class ArticlesCrudAction {
  public static readonly type = '[Articles] Crud action';
  constructor(public operation: CrudOperation, public article?: Article) {}
}
```

So if you'll want to delete an article - you'll dispatch such action:

```js
public deleteArticle(article: Article): void {
  this.store.dispatch(
    new ArticlesCrudAction(CrudOperation.Delete, article)
  );
}
```

This is just a pseudo-code, but I'm not a fan of this approach as I've already seen it before. Explicit is better than implicit. You will need to write some `switch-case` and determine what method of service to use.

If I were you - I would still leave these CRUD actions, as they bring clarity to what is happening. The final code would look something like this:

```js
function setLoading(loading: boolean) {
  return (state: Readonly<ArticlesStateModel>) => ({ ...state, loading });
}

function startLoading() {
  return setLoading(true);
}

function stopLoading() {
  return setLoading(false);
}

@State<ArticlesStateModel>({
  name: 'articles',
  defaults: {
    loading: false,
    articles: []
  }
})
export class ArticlesState {
  @Selector()
  public static isLoading(state: ArticlesStateModel): boolean {
    return state.loading;
  }

  @Selector()
  public static getArticles(state: ArticlesStateModel): Article[] {
    return state.articles;
  }

  constructor(private articlesService: ArticlesService) {}

  @Action(GetAllArticles)
  public getAllArticles(ctx: StateContext<ArticlesStateModel>) {
    return this.request(
      ctx,
      () => this.articlesService.getAllArticles(),
      articles => ctx.patchState({ articles })
    );
  }

  @Action(GetArticleById)
  public getArticleById(ctx: StateContext<ArticlesStateModel>, { id }: GetArticleById) {
    return this.request(ctx, () => this.articlesService.getArticleById(id));
  }

  @Action(DeleteArticle)
  public deleteArticle(ctx: StateContext<ArticlesStateModel>, { article }: DeleteArticle) {
    return this.request(ctx, () => this.articlesService.deleteArticle(article.id));
  }

  @Action(UpdateArticle)
  public updateArticle(ctx: StateContext<ArticlesStateModel>, { article }: UpdateArticle) {
    return this.request(ctx, () => this.articlesService.updateArticle(article));
  }

  @Action(CreateArticle)
  public createArticle(ctx: StateContext<ArticlesStateModel>, { article }: CreateArticle) {
    return this.request(ctx, () => this.articlesService.createArticle(article));
  }

  private request<T>(
    ctx: StateContext<ArticlesStateModel>,
    request: () => Observable<T>,
    callback?: (response: T) => void
  ) {
    ctx.setState(startLoading());

    return request().pipe(
      tap(response => callback && callback(response)),
      finalize(() => ctx.setState(stopLoading()))
    );
  }
}
```

You can also create an additional method where you could patch your state, setting `loading` property to `true` before sending request, and pipe it with `finalize`.

Still this is very abstract and depends on your implementation.

We also introduced [state operators](https://ngxs.gitbook.io/ngxs/advanced/operators) in the `3.4.0` release, that may reduce your code by bringing declarativeness.